# how to import module.exports in webpack

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, package.json

I am trying to refactor some webpack settings (in my package.json) that I currently have, as I have 4 files with almost the same code, some constants are different:

```
"scripts": {
  "build:something": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode=production --progress --config webpack.prod.something.js",
  "build:something2": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode=production --progress --config webpack.prod.something2.js",
  "build:something3": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode=production --progress --config webpack.prod.something3.js",
  "build:something4": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode=production --progress --config webpack.prod.something4.js",
}
```

and this code what shows in the webpack.prod.something1.js, ...

```
'use strict';

const webpack = require('webpack');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const fs = require('fs'); 
const DEFAULTLANG = 'en'; // this is different in each brand
const CURRENT_BRAND = 'something'; // this is different in each brand
const API_URL = ''; // Development Backend API testing URL
const IPG_URL = 'https://test.com'; // this is different in each brand
const packageJson = fs.readFileSync('./package.json');
const version = JSON.parse(packageJson).version || 0;

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        main: './src/js/main.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
    }, ....
```

I tried to create a separated file *settings.js*, with all the **module.exports** code, and import it with require, but it tries to execute **path.resolve** and all the rest of the function inside of it.

I just wanted it to import it and execute all the functions when everything is imported and execute it in each something.js file.

Any Ideas on how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Export it as a function then, like a getSettings function

Comment: hmmm i am going to try that idea